# Facebook, twitter icon please uncoment to get the link

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have tried to make it responsive but instead messing up. kindly help.

```html
<!--HERE is the link-->
<!--https://codepen.io/petitkwoba/pen/yLeVpXQ-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  
<body>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would be helpful to also share code/what you have tried already.

Comment: Please post the CSS & HTML Code snippet. If possible post a stackblitz link. it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using the icon to implement it, you may refer to codes I posted.

```css
.icon {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4267b2;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<span class="icon"><i class=" fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```css
.icon
{
  background-color: blue;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  border-radius: 28px;
}
img{
  padding-top:8px;
  padding-left:9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
<img src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/white/twitter-24.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on StackOverflow.

You should show us what you've tried so we can help you.

Any way, there is few ways to do it.

- Us already "circled" icon.
- Use a div/span to contain the icon (use basic width/height/line-height or use flex to center icon)
- Use "stack" way of Font-awesome ([Documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/#stacked))

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4267b2;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<span class="icon">
    <i class=" fa fa-facebook"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```